# How to change MFCCs to PointList and GMM

Tags: speech-recognition, point, k-means, gaussian, mfcc

I make a emotion-recognition program using comirva package.

and I have a lot of wav files about emotion like angry, happy..

to make a gmm, first, i extracted mfcc features from one of argry files.

what I confused is that how to change mffccs to pointlist.

wich one is correct?
i) changing mfcc extracted from one file to one pointList
ii) chaiging mfccs extracted from many files to one pointlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct is

iii) chaiging mfccs extracted from many files which belong to same emotion (e.g. angry) to one pointlist and to train GMM on them. As a result you should get a set of GMMs which correspond to emotions.

This algorithm for emotion classification is sort of senseless. To detect emotion one requires some other features like pitch and so on. I recommend you to look on real emotion recognition libraries first like openart/openear:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/openart/

Comment: thank you so much. your comment is so useful to me. the reason why i choose mffcc as way of speech recognition is thesis. some thesis sad that mfcc + delta mfcc + gmm combination show the best recognition rate. 


although i want to use library you recommend, i have to use java library, because my team is making a android app. as i knew, it is very hard work to transplant c++ library to java code. isn't it? so i think, it would be better use mfcc + gmm if it is not so sensless.  because i'm begginer in english, my writting is so poor, sorry. and thank you so much again for your support.

Comment: In terms of using openear, you can easily work with C++ and then have a web service so that you can communication with your Android part form C++. Have a look at: [link](https://code.google.com/p/staff/)...